# Passing Multiple Values into an API/Getting Multiple Values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, erp

Here's the issue that I'm working through today. We have an ERP system in place and I need to set up an event to email Purchase Order Authorizers (POA) whenever they have a Purchase Order ready for approval. This is pretty easy to set up for purchase orders where we have a single authorizer. However, some purchase orders need to be reviewed by a group of authorizers, specifically our QA group, before they can get approved.

I can get a list of authorizers for our QA group using the following:

```
select authorize_id from purch_authorize_group_line where authorize_group_id = '30-QA-NUC';
```

This query returns 50 rows of data.

I can also get the USERID associated with an Authorize ID using the following:

```
SELECT purchase_authorizer_api.get_userid('30','104351') FROM DUAL;
```

What I can't figure out is how to pass all values from the first query into the second one. This query:

```
SELECT purchase_authorizer_api.get_userid('30',(select authorize_id from purch_authorize_group_line where authorize_group_id = '30-QA-NUC')) FROM DUAL;
```

returns the error "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row."

So, what I'm wondering, is whether there's a way for me to pass all 50 values from the first query into the second query and get USERIDs for all 50 users. If those USERIDs then I can get a notification email out to the QA group when they have a PO ready to approve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help -

```
DECLARE
    V_VARIABLE VARCHAR2(1024);
BEGIN

FOR REC IN (SELECT AUTHORIZE_ID AS VAL FROM PURCH_AUTHORIZE_GROUP_LINE WHERE AUTHORIZE_GROUP_ID = '30-QA-NUC')
LOOP

SELECT PURCHASE_AUTHORIZER_API.GET_USERID('30',R.VAL) INTO V_VARIABLE FROM DUAL;

..
..
../* You code processing logic */


END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for this.

```
SELECT purchase_authorizer_api.get_userid('30', authorize_id)
       FROM purch_authorize_group_line
       WHERE authorize_group_id = '30-QA-NUC';
```